# Can not execute a PDO query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to put path to images that I put in ftp before, I have 10 different columns

```
 photo1, photo2, photo3
```

This is my code

```
for($i = 1; $i < $number_of_files + 1 ; $i++){

  $column = 'photo' . $i;
  $file = 'gallery/zdjecie-' . $id . '-' . $i;
    $sql = "UPDATE gallery SET :column=:zdjecie WHERE id=:id";
    $go = $db->prepare($sql);
    $go->bindParam(':column', $column);
    $go->bindParam(':zdjecie', $file);
    $go->bindParam(':id', $id);
    $go->execute();
    $go->closeCursor();
    $go = null;
}
```

It displays this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Something is
>   wrong in your syntax obok ''photo1'='gallery/zdjecie-4-1' WHERE
>   id='4'' w linii 1' in

So I wanted to do something like this

in photo1 columns there should be /gallery/zdjecie-X-1 ...
where X is an ID

Comment: `SET :column=:zdjecie` you can't bind a value to a column name. instead of iterating over your columns, you should make *one* update statement for the whole row. that's cleaner, faster and common practice.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong

```
 $sql = "UPDATE gallery SET :column=:zdjecie WHERE id=:id";
```

Do not use the `:` in front of column names, and you cannot make a column name a replaceable parameter

```
$sql = "UPDATE gallery SET column=:zdjecie WHERE id=:id";
```

You would have to do this to make the column name replaceable

```
$sql = "UPDATE gallery SET $column = :zdjecie WHERE id=:id";
```

Looking closer it makes me think you have made a basic erro in your database design.

You should use a seperate table to hold this data with a foreign key of the key of this owning table

Comment: so how can I do that everytime it upload something the column name changes from photo1 to photo2 then to photo3 etc?

Comment: I don't know how to do it tho but it still doesnt work

Comment: nevermind, I had to delete the bindParam for column, thank you!

Comment: Have you removed this line `$go->bindParam(':column', $column);`